# How can get a user by having just their tag? (Ex. xavia#3366)

Tags: node.js, discord.js

If I do something like

```
message.guild.members.get(`name`, message.content).id
```

It gives an error of

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property id of undefined
```

Thanks!

(Removing the .id bit and logging it also gives "undefined".

Comment: ```guild.fetchMembers("Username#1337", 1).then(console.log).catch(console.error)```
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchMembers
Be sure to join the official Discord developer server for your questions to be more easily answered: https://discord.gg/discord-api

Comment: How would I send a message to them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use new `.find()` function. If the user is cached, you can use:

```js
let user = message.client.users.find((user) => user.tag === "xavia#3366");
if(user){
    console.log("There is a member cached with this tag! ID:"+user.id);
} else {
    console.log("There isn't any member cached with this tag...");
}
```